# What does -p do on shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Does on -p [val] from shell start a process at a specific priority?

Comment: The answer is probably no, but I'm not really sure what your question actually is. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: which `shell` are you using? afaik neither bash nor dash nor tclsh nor zsh have a `-p` flag

Comment: @umlaeute: `bash` does have a `-p` option.

Comment: darn you are right (and i did check the man pages before commenting..but obviously my search was faulty); thumbs up

Comment: Its worth noting the `bash` manpage does not list `-p` under the `OPTIONS` section, so it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 7):

The `-p` option in `bash` and `ksh` is related to security.  It is used to prevent the shell reading user-controlled files.

The [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) manual says:

> #### Invoked with unequal effective and real uid/gids
>
> If Bash is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id,
>   and the `-p` option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited
>   from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if
>   they appear in the environment, are ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user
>   id. If the `-p` option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the
>   effective user id is not reset.

The `ksh` manual says:

> A  shell is privileged if the `-p` option is used or if the real user-id or group-id does not match the
>          effective user-id or group-id (see getuid(2),  getgid(2)).   A  privileged  shell  does  not  process
>          $HOME/.profile  nor  the  ENV parameter (see below), instead the file /etc/suid_profile is processed.
>          Clearing the privileged option causes the shell to set its effective user-id (group-id) to  its  real
>          user-id (group-id).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nice` for add or remove priority from your processes.

```
/bin/nice -n NUM command-name
```

In this way you add a scheduling priority.
For your question I suggest to see [this forum page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/what-does-p-do-in-bin-bash-p-809364/).

Answer (score 0):

Use **nice** to run a program with modified scheduling priority

and **renice** to alter priority of running processes

```
renice 16 -p 113344
```

to change priority of process with Pid 113344 to 16